# cocos2d collision not detected in if((self=[super init]))

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

I used a CGRectIntersectsRect to detect the collision of a moving image (anvil) and an image (guy).

The "anvil" moves constantly in a CCRepeatForever and the "guy" moves in a ccTouchesBegan method by the control of the user.

Here it is, very simple:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(guy.boundingBox, anvil1.boundingBox))
{
      pancake = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"pancake.png"];
      pancake.position = ccp(200,200);
      [self addChild:pancake];
}
```

The problem is that the above lines of code do not work in the if((self=[super init])) and only in the ccTouchesBegan, where I have all of the actions for "guy." I do not want to have the image "pancake" appear only if the user taps exactly when the two images collide...if the images EVER collide, regardless of touch events, "pancake" should appear.

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not understand your problem. I'm confused as to what is and is not working, and what you want to achieve here. Why would you want to check for intersection during init? Why not check this during update: so that it is decoupled from touch detection?

Comment: replace init method with onEnter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to criticize but your code doesn't make a lot of sense. Why would you be testing for interestion in an init method for two objects that are constantly in motion throughout your scene? Even if you wanted to show the pancake whenever the two intersected, why don't you load the pancake and make it invisible, then switch it to visible whenever the two objects intersect. This could be done simply by putting the condition in an update method and setting pancake's visible property to true if they intersect or false otherwise.

But to answer the question of "why" that code doesn't work in init is simply because at the point of calling this either one or both of your objects doesn't exist, they simply don't intersect, or their bounding box properties have not been set. I bet they simply don't intersect yet. But that doesn't matter much since there is no reason I can see to check for interestion in an init method. Schedule the update method, create the update method, and place this condition inside of it but rather than create the pancake sprite, you'd be setting the already existing pancake sprite's visibility to TRUE.

Comment: I don't blame you, I'm a complete n00b. This whole time, I managed to write almost an entire game in just the init and ccTouchesBegan. I guess now that I've entirely structured this whole thing incorrectly, I should just recreate the game, with the update method. I suppose I didn't teach myself very well/ the tutorials I watched didn't exactly cover some very important topics. I'm sorry for making you all dumber by my question's expression of my ignorance.

Comment: I wouldn't say it like that. We are all beginners at some point and it takes a really long time and a lot of practice to make games so don't be hard on yourself. Tutorials are usually not that great but that is the nature of tutorials. Keep practicing and asking questions and you will be just fine. Believe me I've made huge mistakes when I first started and it is definitely a rough road when trying to become a game programmer. Remember you are working on something others only dream about.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for your help Allen! Thank you LearnCocos2D and Guru, as well. I'm trying to learn this thing the right way now so I can have an app by September.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck with the game. It is a great feeling to finish and ship something to the iTunes store and I look forward to you achieving that.